# Create a pack in python to network send to C

Tags: python, c++, sockets, pack

First of all, I'm very newbie in python, I've readed python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) and I still don't understand how to that.

So, I need to send that structure:
UDP_PAQUET:

```
 unsigned char type
 char ext[5]
 char data[50]
```

I tried to do this:

```
UDP_PKT = pack('BC5C50',"0x00", "2501", "user05")
```

but I'm getting a:

```
bad char in stuct format
```

Could someone help me a little?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there's no uppercase `C` format specifier in the [struct module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters).

After that, I think that you want to use the `s` specifier for the `ext` and `data` members, and not pass in that first `0x00` value as a string, like:

```
UDP_PKT = pack('B5s50s', 0x00, "2501", "user05")
```

(Note that the size/repeat count appears before the format specifier.)

...which generates a packed string like:

```
'\x002501\x00user05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```